# Aggregating List of Dicts in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can I perform aggregations and analysis on column in a Spark DF that was created from column that contained multiple dictionaries such as the below:

```
rootKey=[Row(key1='value1', key2='value2', key3='value3'), Row(key1='value1', key2='value2', key3='value3'), Row(key1='value1', key2='value2', key3='value3'), Row(key1='value1', key2='value2', key3='value3')]
```

Here is an example of what the column looks like:

```
>>> df.select('column').show(20, False)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|column                                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[1,1,1], [1,2,6], [1,2,13], [1,3,3]]                            |
|[[2,1,1], [2,3,6], [2,4,10]]                                     |
|[[1,1,1], [1,1,6], [1,2,1], [2,2,2], [2,3,6], [1,3,7], [2,4,10]] |
```

An example would be to summarize all of the key values and groupBy a different column.

Comment: Looks like you have a Python list of Spark Row objects... How about you make that a proper Dataframe?

Comment: Thanks. I already read it into a spark dataframe with `spark.read.json(...` and now have a nice DF but the original file was a json with a bunch of dicts per line and one of the values in the dict was a key containing a list of multiple dictionaries. So basically my nested dictionaries became converted to a spark DF with a key containing multiple Rows and values. Just want to aggregate those multiple Rows in the Spark DF. Is that the right though process. Can you elaborate on what you mean by make it a proper DF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `f.explode`:

json_file.json:

```
{"idx":1, "col":[{"k":1,"v1":1,"v2":1},{"k":1,"v1":2,"v2":6},{"k":1,"v1":2,"v2":13},{"k":1,"v1":2,"v2":2}]}
{"idx":2, "col":[{"k":2,"v1":1,"v2":1},{"k":2,"v1":3,"v2":6},{"k":2,"v1":4,"v2":10}]}
```

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df = spark.read.load('file:///home/zht/PycharmProjects/test/json_file.json', format='json')
df = df.withColumn('col', f.explode(df['col']))
df = df.groupBy(df['col']['v1']).sum('col.k')
df.show()


# output:
+---------+-----------------+                                                   
|col['v1']|sum(col.k AS `k`)|
+---------+-----------------+
|        1|                3|
|        3|                2|
|        2|                3|
|        4|                2|
+---------+-----------------+
```